# Modificar las opciones de un select desde otro select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo el siguiente código que funciona bien solo que tiene unos detalles

```
                   <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Categoria:</label>
                          <select class="form-control s-categoria">
                            <option value="0">Selecion de Categoría</option>
                            <option value="1">Volvo</option>
                            <option value="2">Scania Mercedes</option>
                            <option value="3">Repuestos General</option>
                            <option value="4">Repuestos Usados</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Subcategoria:</label>
                          <select class="form-control s2-categoria" disabled>

                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                      $('.s-categoria').change(function(){
                        if($('.s-categoria').val()>0){
                          $('.s2-categoria').prop('disabled', false);
                          if($('.s-categoria').val()==1){
                            $('.s2-categoria').append('<option value="1" selected="selected">Accesorios de Transmisión</option>');
                            $('.s2-categoria').append('<option value="2">Accesorios Eléctricos</option>');
                            $('.s2-categoria').append('<option value="3">Accesorios de Direccón</option>');
                            $('.s2-categoria').append('<option value="4">Accesorios de Motor</option>');
                            $('.s2-categoria').append('<option value="5">Accesorios de Cabina</option>');
                            $('.s2-categoria').append('<option value="6">Frenos</option>');
                          }
                          if($('.s-categoria').val()==2){
                            $('.s2-categoria').append('<option value="1" selected="selected">Repuestos de Cabina Mercedes</option>');
                            $('.s2-categoria').append('<option value="2">Repuestos de Cabina Scania</option>');
                            $('.s2-categoria').append('<option value="3">Repuestos de Motor Scania</option>');
                            $('.s2-categoria').append('<option value="4">Repuestos Eléctricos Scania</option>');
                          }
                          if($('.s-categoria').val()==3){
                            $('.s2-categoria').append('<option value="1" selected="selected">Sofware</option>');
                            $('.s2-categoria').append('<option value="2">Accesorios</option>');
                            $('.s2-categoria').append('<option value="3">Sistema Eléctrico</option>');
                          }
                          if($('.s-categoria').val()==4){
                            $('.s2-categoria').append('<option value="1" selected="selected">Motor</option>');
                          }
                        }
                        if($('.s-categoria').val()==0){
                          $('.s2-categoria').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                        }
                      });
                    </script>
```

el detalle es el siguiente si escojo en el primer select, en el segundo sale una lista, pero al escoger después otra opción, se añaden mas opciones adicionales al segundo select, y si regreso a la primera opción se añaden otra ves repitiendo las opciones en el segundo select, como puedo hacer para que aparezca una lista por cada opción del primer select sin que ocurra los detalles explicados.

gracias por su tiempo

Comment: podrías ponerle un id al segundo select y usar el metodo empty() para vaciarlo cada cuando cambies el primero algo como ("#SegundoSelect").empty() justo antes de tus sentencias `if`

Answer (score 0):

Es porque no eliminas los `option` agregados

```
$('.s2-categoria option').remove();
```